# Incorrect aspect class is executed Spring AOP Schema Based

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

//aspect-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <bean name="referenceAspect"
        class="com.example.reference.audit.aspect.ReferenceAuditAspect"></bean>
    <bean name="mainApplicationTypeAspect"
        class="com.example.maintenance.audit.aspect.MaintApplicationTypeAuditAspect"></bean>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="referenceAspect">
            <!-- @around sysad log annotation -->
            <aop:pointcut id="referencePointCut" expression="@annotation(etisLog)" />
            <aop:around method="auditLogAround" pointcut-ref="referencePointCut" />
        </aop:aspect>

        <aop:aspect ref="mainApplicationTypeAspect">
            <!-- @around sysad log annotation -->
            <aop:pointcut id="mainApplicationTypePointCut" expression="@annotation(etisLog)" />
            <aop:around method="auditLogAround" pointcut-ref="mainApplicationTypePointCut" />
        </aop:aspect>

    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

I have two aspect class:

```
@Component
public class ReferenceAuditAspect {


  public Object auditLogAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ETISLog etisLog)
      throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("INTERCEPTING REFERENCE SERVICE...");
  }
}

@Component
public class MaintApplicationTypeAuditAspect  {


  public Object auditLogAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ETISLog etisLog)
      throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("INTERCEPTING REFERENCE SERVICE...");

  }

}
```

//My pointcut expression

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ETISLog {

}
```

//Intercepting at API Level

```
@ETISLog
  public ResponseEntity<MaintApplicationType> save(
      @RequestBody MaintApplicationType maintApplicationType) {
    LOGGER.info("API: SAVE {}", maintApplicationType);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(maintApplicationTypeService.save(maintApplicationType),
        HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
```

But why does when i run my application and perform save operation under maintApplicationApi, the aspect that always get executed is the ReferenceAuditAspect instead of the mainApplicationTypeAspect. I have a code inside the auditLogAround that performs specific operations.

I followed the documentation here : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html -> 8.3 Section

I also tried removing : `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />` but same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix for this was i created a new Annotation of pointcut expression for each aspect.